# How to distribute Maas360 Bulk Enrollment app to set up 200+ Windows computers

Tags: ibm, mdm

My company is getting started with MaaS to replace our old MDM service but we've hit a roadblock pretty quickly...we have several hundred desktops and laptops that need to be enrolled.

Since everyone's working from home and super security conscious these days, there's a lot of pressure to get all of these devices enrolled as quickly as possible. I've looked at Bulk Enrollment but there doesn't seem to be a whole lot of guidance on how to distribute the Bulk Enrollment exe en masse to large numbers of devices

I spoke with IBM Support but they weren't as helpful as hoped: the suggestion was either to use GPO's to distro the enrollment app or to do it manually...

I'm hoping you guys might have some ideas or been in similar situations and point me in the right direction?
Any help is much appreciated!